# How do I specify what I want to countour plot, In Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code:

```
figure, (ax1, ax3, ax4) = plt.subplots(3)

ax1.set_yscale("linear")
ax1.set_xscale("linear")
ax1.plot(A,B,color='black')
cax = ax1.contourf(X,Y,Z)
cbar= figure.colorbar(cax)

#rest of code
```

Here `A,B,X,Y,Z` are some arrays. Now the `A,B` arrays have a wider range than `X,Y`, but what I want to have on the plot is only the axis from `X,Y` axes.
How can I tell matplotlib to ignore "rest" from the black line plot?
For reference look at this picture:
[image]

EDIT: I don't modify content of A,B as that would be to complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found solution, it was quite simple:

```
figure, (ax1, ax3, ax4) = plt.subplots(3)

ax1.set_yscale("linear")
ax1.set_xscale("linear")
ax1.plot(A,B,color='black')
cax = ax1.contourf(X,Y,Z)
cbar= figure.colorbar(cax)


ax1.set_xlim(min(X),max(X))
ax1.set_ylim(min(Y),max(Y))
```